# Trying to ChrootDirectory an SFTP user to their home directory

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot

I have followed a few examples of how to do this, all of them end up with modifying `sshd_config` to

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match User chubbyninja
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

When I do this, I then `sshd -t` to make sure there are no errors then `service sshd restart`

once it's restarted, I try to SFTP (with filezilla) but I keep getting

```
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "chubbyninja@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 22
Command:    Pass: ********************
Error:  Network error: Software caused connection abort
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

If i revert the config back to its original state, i can SFTP fine, but then i can browse any directory. Where I need users only in their home directory

My default config has this line in it:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Which is what i'm **replacing** with the above details.

I only have access to this machine over ssh, although i do have root access.

**UPDATE**
After following sam_pan_mariusz's advice it appears to get further, but now I get

```
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "chubbyninja@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 22
Error:  Network error: Connection refused
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have also followed Froggiz's advice and changed my config to this:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0007 -f AUTH -l VERBOSE 
Match Group chubbyninja
     ChrootDirectory /home/chubbyninja
     ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0007
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     GatewayPorts no
     X11Forwarding no
```

but I get the original **Software cased connection abort**

I monitor `/var/syslog` but nothing shows up to indicate why there's this error

**UPDATE 3 - Added sshd_config**

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
#PermitRootLogin without-password
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0007 -f AUTH -l VERBOSE

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes



Match Group chubbyninja
        ChrootDirectory /home/chubbyninja
        AllowTCPForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0007
```

Comment: Did you ever get this straightened out?  I'm experiencing a [similar issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309693/sshd-selinux-copy-context-getcon-failed-with-no-such-file-or-directory-sftp-fr).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the "replacing" part in the question, but... when chroot-ing in SSH, *ForceCommand* should refer to the internal subsystem name. In your case, the whole line should read: `ForceCommand sftp`.

If you want to use executable path in *Chroot*, you'll have to prepare proper chroot directory (containing libraries that the executable links to, configs, etc.).

Relevant lines from my working config:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Match User testuser1
    ChrootDirectory /one/dir/path/
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I still get the same error when changing to `ForceCommand sftp` though, as for the resplacing: By default I have `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` so I delete that line and add in `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`

Comment: After going through your answer again, I get a `connection refused` when trying to SFTP now.. so progress perhaps?

Comment: I've extended my answer with a relevant part of my working config from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i set my sftp for specific user

1] create a user

```
 adduser {USER}
```

2] edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
 PasswordAuthentication yes 

 Subsystem sftp
 internal-sftp -u 0007 -f AUTH -l VERBOSE 
 Match Group {USER}
     ChrootDirectory {FOLDER}
     ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0007
     AllowTcpForwarding no
     GatewayPorts no
     X11Forwarding no
```

3] set rights for the user

```
 chmod -R 777 {FOLDER}
```

4] restart ssh

```
service ssh restart
```

replace {USER} by your user
and {FOLDER} by your folder
and it should works ! ;)

can you put your full ssh config ?

Comment: Should I be using `Match Group` or `Match User`? Match User is still giving me software aborted.. this is so confusing! - Are there any logs I can look at to see what the software aborted means?

Comment: when a user is created, it is created with same the groupe ({user}:{user})

Comment: Ahh ok thank you, i'll try with group now.. still the same issue

Comment: the log are in -f VERBOSE but you have to set it in syslog : /etc/rsyslog.conf change "verbose.*    /var/log/sftp.log, btw what is your error message with my conf ?

Comment: Froggiz - I've added the sshd_config and the error message is still Network Error: software caused abort

Comment: remove line : UsePAM yes ;)

Comment: I feel like it's getting closer!.. now it's `Server unexpectedly closed network connection`

Comment: could you try PermitRootLogin = no ?

Comment: This wont effect my current SSH sessions will it? I only have access over SSH to this machine

Comment: yes it will cut your access, mine is commented, but default is yes, sorry for this bad advice ;) (normaly it should not kick you, just block you on the next connexion), i would like to make more test for you but i am a bit busy right now

Comment: No worries Froggiz, i appreciate all the help you've given me so far

Comment: by the way if you comment all other instructions and let only what i posted it should works, then u can add back intructions to test wich one cause trouble