# sftp with chroot without ssh access

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot

I'm trying to have some users able to sftp but not ssh. I've looked at [OpenSSH: Difference between internal-sftp and sftp-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/660160/openssh-difference-between-internal-sftp-and-sftp-server) and [Trying to ChrootDirectory an SFTP user to their home directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/671860/trying-to-chrootdirectory-an-sftp-user-to-their-home-directory#671868)

Inside of sshd_config I have the lines

```
 Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
 AllowUsers <a bunch of users>

 Match group sftponly
      ChrootDirectory /home/%u
      X11Forwarding no
      AllowTcpForwarding no
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Filezilla gives me

```
 Error: Network error: Software caused connection abort
 Error: Could not connect to server
```

When I comment out the `ChrootDirectory /home/%u`
I am able to connect fine.

How can I chroot?

Comment: ah ok thanks! I didn't know to look in the `var/log/auth.log` it says that my users folder was owned by someone else. A thing i've found, only the user's folder needed JUST the owner permission to be root. Marking as dupe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess it's file permissions.
If you use ChrootDirectory *everything* in the path following needs to be owned by root and not group writable (see man sshd_config).

And just to make sure, you did add your users to group sftponly and all that stuff...

Comment: I got it to work as per my comment above. However, it seems that not all of the files inside the users' folder needs to be that way, just /home/<user>.

Comment: Right, just the path specified in the ChrootDirectory.  What's actually *in* that dir is fair game.